# Check for relation laravel and print results

Tags: php, laravel

I have relation, in foreach I check if exists this relation then print result, but if else then print results without relation.

```
@foreach($attr as $at)
@if($at->related)
    <option value="{{ $at->related->id }}">
            @if($at->value)
                {{ $at->related->value }}
            @else
                {{ $at->related->extra['first_name'] ? 'First Name and Lastname: ' . $at->related->extra['first_name'] : '' }} {{ $at->related->extra['last_name'] }} |
                {{ $at->related->extra['email'] ? 'Email: ' . $at->related->extra['email'] : '' }} |
                {{ $at->related->extra['telephone'] ? 'Tel: ' . $at->related->extra['telephone'] : '' }}
            @endif
    </option>
@else
    <option value="{{ $at->id }}">
        @if($at->value)
            {{ $at->value }}
        @else
            {{ $at->extra['first_name'] ? 'First Name and Lastname: ' . $at->extra['first_name'] : '' }} {{ $at->extra['last_name'] }} |
            {{ $at->extra['email'] ? 'Email: ' . $at->extra['email'] : '' }} |
            {{ $at->extra['telephone'] ? 'Tel: ' . $at->extra['telephone'] : '' }}
        @endif
    </option>
@endif @endforeach
```

I get all results and with relation and without relation. How I can fix this? Condition is not working.

In `$attr` I have array with models Attribute:

```
$attrs = Attribute::with('related')->get()->groupBy('attr_id');
```

Comment: becouse laravel [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) eager loading. One solution must be check isset($at->related), ore $at->getRelations()

Comment: isset not working..

Comment: try getRelations method, after 5 minute i add whole answer how to do it

Comment: getRelations not working :) Ok. Wait

Comment: Share "Attribute" Model to view the relation

Comment: and than it will help me? and I shared variabls $attrs to view

Comment: I add my answer try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `groupBy('attr_id')` Laravel Collection creates collection of a collection based on id.

The correct implementation would be a nested foreach loop to iterate through collections.

Collection:

```
$attrCollection = Attribute::with('related')->get()->groupBy('attr_id');
```

Blade file:

```
@foreach($attrCollection as $attr)
    @foreach($attr as $at)
        @if(! is_null($at->related) )
            <option value="{{ $at->related->id }}">
                @if($at->value)
                    {{ $at->related->value }}
                @else
                    {{ $at->related->extra['first_name'] ? 'First Name and Lastname: ' . $at->related->extra['first_name'] : '' }} {{ $at->related->extra['last_name'] }} |
                    {{ $at->related->extra['email'] ? 'Email: ' . $at->related->extra['email'] : '' }} |
                    {{ $at->related->extra['telephone'] ? 'Tel: ' . $at->related->extra['telephone'] : '' }}
                @endif
            </option>
        @else
            <option value="{{ $at->id }}">
                @if($at->value)
                    {{ $at->value }}
                @else
                    {{ $at->extra['first_name'] ? 'First Name and Lastname: ' . $at->extra['first_name'] : '' }} {{ $at->extra['last_name'] }} |
                    {{ $at->extra['email'] ? 'Email: ' . $at->extra['email'] : '' }} |
                    {{ $at->extra['telephone'] ? 'Tel: ' . $at->extra['telephone'] : '' }}
                @endif
            </option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: @Dumitru Are you sure the condition is ignored? and the relation does exist in the db?

Comment: @Dumitru use the loops as @rajendar wrote. Update query like,  `$attrCollection = Attribute::with('related')->withCount('related')->get()->groupBy('attr_id');` and if condition like, `@if($at->related_count > 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing if condition from

```
@if($at->related)
```

to

```
@if(!empty($at->related))
```

Comment: Call to a member function isEmpty() on null

Comment: try with count function

Comment: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Comment: replace count with empty() function

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
@if($at->related)
```

with

```
@if(!$at->related->isEmpty())
```